# How to prove a solution not optimal using duality?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems, simplex-method

I have been given an LPP problem and asked to prove the basic solution $(x_1, x_2)$ is not optimal, but every time I am solving it using simplex and the duality method the objective function keeps coming same ($\max z = \min w$). What am I missing here?

The original model/problem:

> $$\max z = 2x_1 + 4x_2 + 4x_3 - 3x_4$$
> $$\text{Subject to: }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
> $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ≤ 4$$
> $$x_1 + 4x_2 + x_4 = 8$$
> $$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 ≥ 0$$
>
> Use the dual problem to verify the basic solution $x_1, x_2$ is not optimal.

Comment: What is the LPP problem? And use the edit function to improve your question.

Comment: kindly include more details of your attempt, it's difficult to find your mistake if you don't show your working

Comment: It's Max z = 2x1 + 4x2 + 4x3 - 3x4.    Subject to x1 + x2 + x3 ≤ 4, x1 + 4x2 + x4 = 8 x1, x2, x3, x4 ≥ 0 Use the dual problem to verify the basic solution x1, x2 is not optimal. Please help me with this. Stuck here since quite a long time now.

Comment: can you include your attempt in the original post?